# How to send data/variable from controller to other controller in codeigniter without using session?

Tags: php, codeigniter, session-variables

How could I send data/variable from controller to other controller in codeigniter without using session?

I know how to send data from controller to other controller using session but I don't want to use it as it's giving me problem. If I use session, data I need to send will be used in many pages.

Example of the Data from controller 1 is $id (which I want to use on the other controller), but in the controller 2. If I open many pages, I only get the same data which is not what I expected. In controller 2, if I'm in page 1 I need $id = 1 while if I'm in page 2 I need the $id = 2. Any help with me appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: use redirect with `'your_url/'.$id`...

Comment: Check this link: http://stackoverflow.com/a/16778572/4198099

Comment: Thanks for the answer @PraveenKumar, how could I use it? can you provide me example?

Comment: @RaviHirani, thanks. I will check it.

Comment: @VandolphReyes check my answer below..

Answer (score 0):

GET -- It's your choice ?

if yes then.. use [URI Class](https://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/libraries/uri.html)

http://example.com/index.php/news/local/1

segment(1) = "news"

segment(2) = "local"

segment(3) = "1" <-- your $id

Controller

```
$id = $this->uri->segment(3);
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but I don't prefer segments as it's not safe for other modules. Sorry I forgot to mention in my question also.

Comment: create your libaries -- https://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/general/creating_libraries.html

Comment: @VisarutSae-pueng Codeigniter doc's for old and new now on the codeIgniter official website http://www.codeigniter.com/docs

Answer (score 0):

`test.php` Controller File :

```
Class Test {
 function demo() {
  echo "Hello";
 }
}
```

`test1.php` Controller File :

```
Class Test1 {
 function demo2() {
  require('test.php');
  $test = new Test();
  $test->demo();
 }
}
```

But using `require` like this in codeigniter is not a good idea...

Comment: Thanks for the answer. But I can't use redirect.

The controller 1 has it's own view and it's should run/work every time. I just need to get the id of that certain controller and use it in the other controller.

Comment: do you want to use another controller's function ??

Comment: Yes, I'm using the controller 2 and I need the $id's from the controller 1.

Comment: Copy that function to some helper and use that helper.... Or save controller values to some constant and access it in second controller...

Comment: Thanks. But how could I use the path or the php file of the require in codeigniter? I tried like this require_once(base_url() .'application/modules/sample/controllers/sample.php'); but it's not working.

Comment: you should not use require to load controllers with in controllers as it not the best way. You should use HMVC.

Comment: @wolfgang1983 exactly what I'm thinking also. Any solution with my problem?